# Database tools for CakePHP 

Tags: cakephp

I'm a newbie to CakePHP and was wondering if there is any tool that can show my model classes and their relationship in a visual / graphical environment?

Answer (score 3):

You could try [cakeapp.com](http://cakeapp.com/), though it works on the table level, and not on the model level.

Answer (score 2):

I was using an UML tool for a while called poseidon. They apparently had a for pay module that would let you import your PHP classes and it would pull up UML models for them. 
Disclaimer: I never used that portion of the tool. The UML mapping was cool though.

Comment: http://www.gentleware.com/uml-software-community-edition.html

Answer (score 2):

Give MySQL Workbench a try.

WB 5.1:
- replaced DBDesigner (Data Modeling)

WB 5.2 (in beta):
- replaces MySQL Query Browser
- replaces MySQL Administrator

And, here are ORM Plugins for Propel, Doctrine, Symfonny, CakePHP:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?153,208229

- MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 2):

You can also try Skipper, which is ERD tool with a support for CakePHP model attributes. You can create the whole model visually with all model attributes and than export the model to php files with generated classes. [www.skipper18.com/en/frameworks/cakephp](https://www.skipper18.com/en/frameworks/cakephp).

Answer (score 2):

Try out PHPMyAdmin [Designer View](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/phpmyadmin-designer-view).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [CakePHP MWB Plugin](https://github.com/13i/mwb) it generates schema files from MySQL workbench files

Answer (score 1):

I usually build my database schema using MySQL workbench.

There are some experimental plug-ins for the latest version that will output the schema files, but I've not had much luck getting them to work.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use [DBDesigner](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/) *(Windows and Linux only)* to visualise my schema. This can be exported to SQL CREATE TABLE statements. Once all my tables had been created I would just use the bake utility, as others have suggested, to scaffold out all the code - it's a great way to learn the framework.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the [CAKE Bake utility](http://book.cakephp.org/view/113/Code-Generation-with-Bake). The advantage of using Cake is to rapidly develop your application(s) based on the model schema. Once you design the database tables, cake bake will allow you to create all of the CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) pages with all of the relationships included.